# Setting lighting in ARKit framework

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

Ok, I'm new to `SceneKit` and `ARKit` here and I just want to set any models I add to my scene to have a certain, bright lighting. I have tried all different configurations of the automatically update lighting settings with ARSceneView, however the only thing that really creates a discernible difference is `autoenablesDefaultLighting`:

```
func setup() {

    antialiasingMode = .multisampling4X
    //autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
    contentScaleFactor = 1.3

    if let camera = pointOfView?.camera {
        camera.wantsHDR = true
        camera.wantsExposureAdaptation = true
        camera.exposureOffset = -1
        camera.minimumExposure = -1
        camera.maximumExposure = 3
    }
}
```

Regardless of the lighting obtained from the camera (as I know ArKit is able to do), I just want to set 1 lighting setting always. I want my scene contents to be lit like this:

[image]

Is this possible? What would I set `sceneView.scene.lightingEnvironment` equal to in order to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you should be able to create a SCNNode in a position and then add a SCNLight to it:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlight